# What lock/unlock button does on recent apps screen?

Tags: recents-screen

On recent apps screen there is a lock/unlock button on each and every app, I want to know what's it's function. I am attaching screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: What version of Android is this?

Comment: It's Marshmallow.

Comment: Interesting, because I've never seen that lock/unlock button before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you lock an app in recents and click on *tap to clear*, it will stay in *recents*. Apps not locked will be cleared (that kills all the running apps without the need to kill each one separately)

Comment: I thought the same, but after you answer I realized it's bit different behaviour wise. The moment you lock an app and press the clear button, it clears all the app at that moment but when next time you press the recent apps button you will find locked app there. Cheers!

Comment: Exactly. It is to ensure that locked apps are always kept alive